# IllegalStateException in collapseActionView since updating to Support library 23

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout of `AppBarLayout` with a `Toolbar` and a `ViewPager` with 3 tabs.
Each tab supports search-mode via `Toolbar`'s `ActionMode` using a `SearchView`.
When we update our app to use the new `Support library 23.0.1` (targeting API 23, and using build tools 23.0.1) exiting the search mode crashes the app on the following stack:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.package.name, PID: 3021
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3937)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3787)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3728)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3701)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.addChildrenForExpandedActionView(Toolbar.java:1809)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.collapseItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2048)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.collapseItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1345)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.collapseActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:705)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.collapseActionView(Toolbar.java:570)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$3.onClick(Toolbar.java:1065)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19873)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Reverting back to `Support library 22.0.1` everything works fine.
I'm seeing my `onMenuItemActionCollapse` callback called, and returning true, but then it seems to crash outside of my code.

Comment: opened an Android issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused since we were manually adding and removing the **home** view from the toolbar - looks like in Support library 23, this special button was placed in **hidden views** collection when the **search view** was collapsed and our changes to the view clashed with this logic.

The solution was to toggle the **home** button visibility instead and this solved the crash

Comment: Any chance you have any code to show how you solved this?

I am running into the same issue when collapsing my search view.